# how to serialize parameters using axios

Tags: ecmascript-6, axios

How would I serialize url parameters for use with [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)? My parameters are just numbers in array `[1,2]`. Here is my code so far

```
     axios({
       method: 'delete',
       url: '/api/'
     })
```

My request url will be something like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/?id=1&id=2

I looked at the `paramsSerializer`method that axios has but its confusing how it can be used or whether its even appropriate in my case. Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

the `config` object of `axios.get` accepts `params`. In `params` you can specify your array and it will do the conversion for you.

Here is an example:

```
axios.get('/api/', {
  params: {
   id: [1,2]
  }
})
```

This will make a request which looks like this:

```
/api/?id[]=1&id[]=2
```